# jar, no main manifest found

Tags: java, jar, windows-7-x64

after a week I am no longer able to call main-classes of jar-files without adding the main-class to the manifest.mf. I don't know what I've broken so far.

I am trying the following:
compiling a jar (for hadoop for example) and calling it with

```
yarn -jar PathToMyJarFile ClassWithAMain Param1 Param2..
```

also I could start it with java instead of yarn, that doesnt matter.

My problem is:
The jars I compiled last week now throw an error
`no main manifest found in PathToMyJarFile` (or whatever the translation from the German `Hauptmanifestattribut` would be)

I explicit called the Class with main function and setting up a certain class-file is not a solution for my problem, because I also use jar files with more then one class containing a main.
Even a quite simple `helloWorld` program with just a `System.out.println` and only one class, I cannot call with

```
java -jar PathToJarFile ClassName.
```

Any suggestions?

I tried to do this again with deactivated antivir and firewall with the same result. I also reinstalled my jdk and jre (same version as before).

`JavaVersion: 1.8.0_51` and didn't changed since quite a long time

`OS: Windows 7U64`

Comment: Do you have a space in the path to your JAR file ?

Comment: nope, I also put it in ""

Comment: Remove the quotes. From what I read here and there, they can cause your problem.

Comment: it does not work either with or without quotes even when I copy the jar to D:\ with rights for everyone to read and write and call it with `java -jar jarfile Class` it does not work

Comment: The other comments I find are all about Java security. It wants to check the name of your JAR file against its manifest. But I took a look in Java's security options and found nothing obvious.

Comment: thanks for your help so far, but as i already said, the jar files which worked a week ago now need a mainClass specified in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

Im terribly sorry for that question, I just had to use
`yarn jar jarfile class`
instead of
`yarn -jar jarfile class`

incredible stupid of mine, but I mixed calling a jar with java for calling it with hadoop...

Can be closed.